# Laravel: Form model binding to inputs with options

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I've created a form using laravel's form model binding.

In the form, I've created the form fields needed to display the model info. When writing out the minimal structure everything populates fine:

```
{{ Form::model( $user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'put' )) }}

    {{ Form::label('first_name', "First Name")}}
    {{ Form::text('first_name')}}
...
```

Set up this way, the `first_name` value from my model is populated automatically when the page loads just like I expect/want it.

The problem comes when I try to specify options for the text input. I'm using bootstrap so I'd like to add a `form-control` class and I'd also like a placeholder in the input field. To do this I defined my text input like so:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name',  array('placeholder' => "e.g. Zoe", 'class' => 'form-control'))}}
```

Note that the second parameter for the text value is empty. This is because I want that to be entered by the model binding without having to add something like `$user->first_name` because then what's the point of model binding?

If I leave it like this I get an error because `Form::text()` [expects a string for the value](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#_text), but if I fix it by entering something like:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', '',  array('placeholder' => "e.g. Zoe", 'class' => 'form-control'))}}
```

Then I get a blank value because I'm giving it a blank string.

Is there a way that I can use form model binding in laravel to fill in the value AND still pass in the options array for my placeholder and class definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just put `Input::old()` there:

```
{{ Form::text('first_name', Input::old('first_name'),  array('placeholder' => "e.g. Zoe", 'class' => 'form-control'))}}
```

So what happens is:

1. Laravel looks for any old input, which it will use as the first option (to repopulate your form with the input data if there is a validation error.
2. If no old Input is found, it will then revert to the modal data

Comment: In my case i don't want to display old input value. So i just replaced Input::old() with null. It works..

Comment: In Laravel 5, `$user->first_name` behaves exact the same as `Input::old('first_name')` as default value. What's the point of that? However, when I have to set a default value by myself, the form model binding doesn't save me work.